# Google appengine Cron jobs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron-task

Can we specify Cron jobs dynamically? I want to define a task to occur at some time in future .How can I achieve that functionality? This is need to be done in Google App Engine. The ony way that I have found is to do polling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Task Queues, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/). Task queues have the same duration constraint of Cron Jobs (10 minutes), and you can specify the time at which the Task will be executed with the `countdownMillis` method on the `TaskOptions` object. For example:

```
Queue myQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue("myQueue");
myQueue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/myTask").countdownMillis(2000));
```

will delay the execution of the task at URL `/myTask` on the queue `myQueue` by 2 seconds. Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue) to understand how to properly configure a task queue for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use task queues. Use countdown for example to control when it starts.